# Method Not Allowed (update)

Tags: laravel

Почему-то ошибка при отправке запроса на обновление.

Есть форма с ингредиентом. Код ниже:

```
<form id="form-update-ingredient" action="{{ route('ingredient.update', $ingredient->id) }}" method="post">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col my-recipe">
        Добавление Игредиента
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="ingredientName" class="col-2 col-form-label">Название</label>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input id="ingredientName" type="text" class="form-control" name="ingredientName" required
                       placeholder="Название ингредиента" value="{{ $ingredient->name }}" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть функция, которая отрабатывает при клике на кнопку. Код ниже:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: $('#form-update-ingredient').attr('action'),
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        ingredientName: $('#ingredientName').val()
    },
    success: function () {
```

Роут зарегестрирован:

```
Route::resource('ingredient', 'IngredientController');
```

И вот сам метод контроллера:

```
public function update(UpdateIngredientRequest $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $input = Utility::cleanField([
            $request->get('ingredientName')
        ]);

        $ingredient = Ingredient::find($id);
        $ingredient->update(['name' => $input[0]]);
    } else {
        return response()->view('errors.403', [], 403);
    }
}
```

Но всё равно пишет ошибку (405 Method not Allowed)
В чём может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кеш маршрутов и повторно закэшировать `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: а почему в форме PUT, а в аяксе POST?

Comment: Вы используете именованный маршрут в форме, но он у вас не зарегистрирован: `Route::resource('ingredient', 'IngredientController')->names(['update' => 'ingredient.update', ... другие имена маршрутов]);`